# Return a struct from a c++ function to c# then an array UPDATE

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have read through maybe 100+ posts on this over 2 weeks and have got myself totally confused. This is for a wrapper i'm writing over the BlueSoleil stack.

In c++

```
typedef char BTINT8;
typedef unsigned char BTUINT8;
typedef unsigned char BTUCHAR; /* extended ASII character, 0 - 255 */
typedef unsigned char BTBOOL;
typedef short BTINT16;
typedef unsigned short BTUINT16;
typedef long BTINT32;
typedef unsigned long BTUINT32;
typedef void * BTLPVOID;

typedef BTUINT32 BTDEVHDL;
typedef BTUINT32 BTSVCHDL;
typedef BTUINT32 BTCONNHDL;
typedef BTUINT32 BTSHCHDL;
typedef BTUINT32 BTSDKHANDLE;

typedef struct _BlueToothDevice
{
    BTDEVHDL rmt_device_handle;
    BTINT32  rmt_device_num;
    BTUINT32 rmt_device_class;
    BTUINT8  rmt_device_name[64];

} BLUETOOTHDEVICE;

typedef struct _BlueToothDevices
{
    BTUINT32 num_rmt_devices;
    BLUETOOTHDEVICE rmt_btd[100];
} BLUETOOTHDEVICES;

public ref class RemoteDeviceDiscovery
{       
public:
    int GetBTD(BLUETOOTHDEVICE btd);
};
```

In C#

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct BluetoothDevice
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
        public UInt32 rmt_device_handle;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        public Int32 rmt_device_num;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
        public UInt32 rmt_device_class;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 248)]
        public IntPtr rmt_device_name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct BluetoothDevices
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
        public UInt32 num_rmt_devices;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
        public List<BluetoothDevice> BluetoothDeviceInfo;
    }

static void Main()
{
    var rd = new RemoteDeviceDiscovery();

    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = new BluetoothDevice();
    var i = rd.GetBTD(ref bluetoothDevice);
}
```

Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleWrapperTest.Program.BluetoothDevice' to 'BlueSoleilWrapper._BlueToothDevice'

So can someone point out where I have gone wrong please.

Jim

UPDATE

Have the c++/cli wrapper compiling with the following header code

```
public ref class RemoteDeviceDiscovery
{
    /* Remote Device Discovery */

public:

    int^ GetBTD(_BlueToothDevices % btds);
};
```

and cpp code

```
array<Byte>^ MakeManagedArray(unsigned char* input, int len)
{
    array<Byte>^ result = gcnew array<Byte>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        result[i] = input[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int^ RemoteDeviceDiscovery::GetBTD(_BlueToothDevices % btds)
{
    unsigned char name[] = "Test";

    _BlueToothDevice entry;

    btds.num_rmt_devices = 1;
    entry.rmt_device_class = 1;
    entry.rmt_device_handle = 2;
    entry.rmt_device_num = 3;
    entry.rmt_device_name = MakeManagedArray(name, sizeof(name));

    btds.rmt_btd[0] = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();
    btds.rmt_btd[0] = %entry;

    return 99;
}
```

Problem is now in the C# code

```
var rd = new RemoteDeviceDiscovery();

_BlueToothDevices bluetoothDevices = new _BlueToothDevices();

var i = rd.GetBTD(bluetoothDevices);

var rmt_device_handle = bluetoothDevices.rmt_btd[0].rmt_device_handle;
```

When compiling I get 'GetBTD' is not supported by the language and everything I have seen so far as solutions hasn't worked.  Appreciate any further assistance.

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got a working answer !  Many thanks to rpeshkov you pointed me in the right direction and i'm glad I learnt something from it all.

In the header

```
public ref class RemoteDeviceDiscovery
{
    /* Remote Device Discovery */
public:
    int GetBTD(_BlueToothDevices ^% btds);
};
```

In the cpp code

```
int RemoteDeviceDiscovery::GetBTD(_BlueToothDevices ^% btds)
{
    unsigned char name0[] = "Test0";
    unsigned char name1[] = "Test1";

    _BlueToothDevice^ entry = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();

    entry->rmt_device_class = 1;
    entry->rmt_device_handle = 2;
    entry->rmt_device_num = 3;
    entry->rmt_device_name = MakeManagedArray(name0, sizeof(name0));

    btds->num_rmt_devices = 2;
    btds->rmt_btd[0] = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();
    btds->rmt_btd[0] = entry;

    entry = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();

    entry->rmt_device_class = 4;
    entry->rmt_device_handle = 5;
    entry->rmt_device_num = 6;
    entry->rmt_device_name = MakeManagedArray(name1, sizeof(name1));

    btds->rmt_btd[1] = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();
    btds->rmt_btd[1] = entry;

    return 99;
}
```

and finally in the C# code (this is of course just a bare bones test to development a framework)

```
var rd = new RemoteDeviceDiscovery();

_BlueToothDevices bluetoothDevices = new _BlueToothDevices();

var i = rd.GetBTD(ref bluetoothDevices);

var rmt_device_handle = bluetoothDevices.rmt_btd[0].rmt_device_handle;
```

Comment: Damm !  There's a bug in the .cpp code.  I think since entry is passed to the array by ref it of course only shows the last.  Didn't spot that.

Comment: Fixed.  See amendment below.  Also edited the cpp code above.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using C++\CLI, not plain C++. If you're using `RemoteDeviceDiscovery` directly then you have to instantiate `BLUETOOTHDEVICE`, not trying to create your own structure.

If you can't use `BLUETOOTHDEVICE` because it's not publicly visible, you can write some sort of adapter for `RemoteDeviceDiscovery` class that will be taking your structure and mapping it on `BLUETOOTHDEVICE`.

Comment: rpeshkov, 
Been awhile since I did any c++ coding !  The two structs BLUETOOTHDEVICE and BLUETOOTHDEVICES are in my wrapper code.  How do I make them public to I can instantiate an instance in the C# code ?

Comment: Jim, googled about C++\CLI structs. I guess you need to define them as `public value struct` to make them managed and to be able to use them in C# code. Structs in your code are native (not managed) C++ structs.

Comment: Ok got the new managed classes worked out.  Now to get the functions sorted out in the .cpp    

 public ref class _BlueToothDevice

 {
 public:
  _BlueToothDevice(){}
  BTDEVHDL rmt_device_handle;
  BTINT32  rmt_device_num;
  BTUINT32 rmt_device_class;
  array<BTUINT8>^  rmt_device_name = gcnew array<BTUINT8>(64);
 };

 public ref class _BlueToothDevices
 {
 public:
  _BlueToothDevices(){}
  BTUINT32 num_rmt_devices;
  array<_BlueToothDevice^>^ rmt_btd = gcnew array<_BlueToothDevice^>(100);
 };

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking in the assembly that defines the class `RemoteDeviceDiscovery` (F12 in Microsoft Visual Studio), and see if you can find that assembly's definition of `BlueSoleilWrapper._BlueToothDevice`.  Then use that definition directly. `ConsoleWrapperTest.Program.BluetoothDevice` will never map to `BlueSoleilWrapper._BlueToothDevice`, regardless of how close your definition matches the one in the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement .cpp code

```
int RemoteDeviceDiscovery::GetBTD(_BlueToothDevices ^% btds)
{
    unsigned char name0[] = "Test0";
    unsigned char name1[] = "Test1";

    _BlueToothDevice^ entry = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();

    entry->rmt_device_class = 1;
    entry->rmt_device_handle = 2;
    entry->rmt_device_num = 3;
    entry->rmt_device_name = MakeManagedArray(name0, sizeof(name0));

    btds->num_rmt_devices = 2;
    btds->rmt_btd[0] = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();
    btds->rmt_btd[0] = entry;

    entry = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();

    entry->rmt_device_class = 4;
    entry->rmt_device_handle = 5;
    entry->rmt_device_num = 6;
    entry->rmt_device_name = MakeManagedArray(name1, sizeof(name1));

    btds->rmt_btd[1] = gcnew _BlueToothDevice();
    btds->rmt_btd[1] = entry;

    return 99;
}
```